# Finding a substring in the members of an list with perl

Tags: perl

Trying figure out the fastest way filter an long array, by finding an substring in the members, with the next methods:

- `$str =~ /\.xml/`           - find the ".xml" somewhere in the string
- `$str =~ /\.xml$/`          - find ".xml" at the end of string
- `substr($str,-4) eq ".xml"` - are the last 4 chars ".xml"?
- `rindex($str, ".xml")`      - any occurence of ".xml"
- `(length($str) - rindex($str,".xml")) == 4` - are the last 4 chars ".xml"?

I tried all the above with the `while/if/push` and inside of a `grep`, with the next code (**UPDATED with the ideas from the comments**)

```
use 5.016;
use warnings;
use Benchmark qw(:all);

my $nmax = 5_000_000;
my @list = map { sprintf "a%s.%s", int(rand(100000000)), (int(rand(2))%2?"txt":"xml") } 1..$nmax;

cmpthese(10, {
        'whl_match'    => sub { my @xml; while(my ($i, $x) = each @list) { push(@xml, $x) if( $x =~ /\.xml/  )}; },
        'whl_matchend' => sub { my @xml; while(my ($i, $x) = each @list) { push(@xml, $x) if( $x =~ /\.xml$/ )}; },
        'whl_matchendz'=> sub { my @xml; while(my ($i, $x) = each @list) { push(@xml, $x) if( $x =~ /\.xml\z/ )}; },
        'whl_substr'   => sub { my @xml; while(my ($i, $x) = each @list) { push(@xml, $x) if( substr($x,-4) eq ".xml" )}; },
        'whl_rindex'   => sub { my @xml; while(my ($i, $x) = each @list) { push(@xml, $x) if( rindex($x,".xml") >= 0 )}; },
        'whl_lenrindex'=> sub { my @xml; while(my ($i, $x) = each @list) { push(@xml, $x) if((length($x)-rindex($x,".xml"))==4)};},

        'for_match'    => sub { my @xml; for my $x (@list) { push(@xml, $x) if( $x =~ /\.xml/  )}; },
        'for_matchend' => sub { my @xml; for my $x (@list) { push(@xml, $x) if( $x =~ /\.xml$/ )}; },
        'for_matchendz'=> sub { my @xml; for my $x (@list) { push(@xml, $x) if( $x =~ /\.xml\z/ )}; },
        'for_substr'   => sub { my @xml; for my $x (@list) { push(@xml, $x) if( substr($x,-4) eq ".xml" )}; },
        'for_rindex'   => sub { my @xml; for my $x (@list) { push(@xml, $x) if( rindex($x,".xml") >= 0 )}; },
        'for_lenrindex'=> sub { my @xml; for my $x (@list) { push(@xml, $x) if((length($x)-rindex($x,".xml"))==4)};},

        'grp_match'    => sub { my @xml = grep { /\.xml/ }  @list; },
        'grp_matchend' => sub { my @xml = grep { /\.xml$/ } @list; },
        'grp_matchendz'=> sub { my @xml = grep { /\.xml\z/ } @list; },
        'grp_substr'   => sub { my @xml = grep { substr($_,-4) eq ".xml" } @list; },
        'grp_rindex'   => sub { my @xml = grep { rindex($_,".xml") >= 0 } @list; },
        'grp_lenrindex'=> sub { my @xml = grep { (length($_) - rindex($_,".xml")) == 4 } @list; },
});
```

The result on my carp notebook.

```
              s/iter whl_matchend whl_matchendz grp_matchendz grp_matchend whl_lenrindex whl_match whl_substr grp_match whl_rindex for_matchend for_matchendz for_lenrindex for_match grp_lenrindex for_substr for_rindex grp_substr grp_rindex
whl_matchend    4.48           --           -0%          -10%         -12%          -17%      -21%       -24%      -25%       -32%         -47%          -47%          -67%      -70%          -70%       -73%       -73%       -77%       -78%
whl_matchendz   4.46           0%            --           -9%         -11%          -17%      -21%       -23%      -25%       -32%         -46%          -46%          -67%      -69%          -70%       -73%       -73%       -76%       -78%
grp_matchendz   4.05          11%           10%            --          -2%           -9%      -13%       -15%      -17%       -25%         -41%          -41%          -63%      -66%          -67%       -70%       -70%       -74%       -76%
grp_matchend    3.96          13%           13%            2%           --           -6%      -11%       -14%      -15%       -24%         -40%          -40%          -62%      -66%          -66%       -70%       -70%       -73%       -75%
whl_lenrindex   3.70          21%           21%            9%           7%            --       -5%        -8%       -9%       -18%         -35%          -35%          -60%      -63%          -64%       -67%       -67%       -72%       -73%
whl_match       3.53          27%           27%           15%          12%            5%        --        -3%       -5%       -14%         -32%          -32%          -58%      -61%          -62%       -66%       -66%       -70%       -72%
whl_substr      3.42          31%           30%           18%          16%            8%        3%         --       -2%       -12%         -30%          -30%          -57%      -60%          -61%       -65%       -65%       -69%       -71%
grp_match       3.36          33%           33%           20%          18%           10%        5%         2%        --       -10%         -29%          -29%          -56%      -59%          -60%       -64%       -64%       -69%       -71%
whl_rindex      3.02          48%           48%           34%          31%           22%       17%        13%       11%         --         -21%          -21%          -51%      -55%          -56%       -60%       -60%       -65%       -67%
for_matchend    2.40          87%           86%           69%          65%           55%       47%        43%       40%        26%           --           -0%          -38%      -43%          -44%       -50%       -50%       -56%       -59%
for_matchendz   2.39          87%           87%           69%          65%           55%       47%        43%       40%        26%           0%            --          -38%      -43%          -44%       -50%       -50%       -56%       -59%
for_lenrindex   1.49         201%          200%          172%         166%          149%      137%       130%      126%       103%          61%           61%            --       -8%          -10%       -19%       -19%       -29%       -33%
for_match       1.36         229%          227%          197%         191%          172%      159%       151%      146%       122%          76%           76%            9%        --           -2%       -11%       -12%       -23%       -27%
grp_lenrindex   1.33         237%          236%          204%         198%          178%      165%       157%      153%       127%          80%           80%           12%        2%            --        -9%        -9%       -21%       -26%
for_substr      1.21         271%          270%          235%         228%          207%      192%       184%      178%       150%          98%           98%           23%       13%           10%         --        -0%       -13%       -18%
for_rindex      1.20         272%          271%          236%         229%          208%      193%       184%      179%       151%          99%           99%           23%       13%           10%         0%         --       -13%       -18%
grp_substr      1.05         326%          325%          285%         277%          252%      235%       226%      220%       188%         128%          128%           41%       30%           27%        15%        15%         --        -6%
grp_rindex     0.990         352%          351%          309%         300%          274%      256%       246%      239%       205%         142%          142%           50%       38%           34%        22%        22%         6%         --
```

I repeated the test many times, and always got the above order.

---

## Question 1.

As I expected, the `grep` is faster as the similar `while/if/push`, but surprised me the next:

Comparing:

```
              s/iter
whl_matchend    4.54
grp_matchend    3.98
```

the `grep` is only **slightly faster** as the similar `while/if/push`.

Why e.g. in the next:

```
whl_substr      3.23
grp_substr      1.05
```

The `grep` is **3 times faster** as the `while/if/push`. So, why the `grep` is nearly 3 times faster as `while/if/push` when doing `substr` and not so fast (only 14%) if doing `/regex-match/`? Similarly, this can be seen an any "string oprration".

*With other words, the* `grep {/regex/}` *has only **slight** speed increase above the* `while/if/push`, *but the* `grep {substr}` *has **huge** speed increase. **Why**?*

---

## Question 2

Another surprise (at least for me) is the next: Why the `$str =~ /\.xml/` is faster as `$str =~ /\.xml$/`? I expecting, than specifying the `$` will speed up the rexex, *because not need search in the whole string* - but that is an wrong assumption, as tested with the next too:

```
use 5.016;
use warnings;
use Benchmark qw(:all);

my $str = "a38877283.xml";
cmpthese(10, {
    'match'     => sub { $str =~ /\.xml/  for (1..5_000_000) },
    'matchend'  => sub { $str =~ /\.xml$/ for (1..5_000_000) },
    'matchendz' => sub { $str =~ /\.xml\z/ for (1..5_000_000) },  #updated the \z
});
```

for the `perl 5, version 20, subversion 0 (v5.20.0) built for darwin-2level` (perlbrew)

```
          s/iter  matchend matchendz     match
matchend    2.32        --       -1%      -64%
matchendz   2.30        1%        --      -63%
match      0.844      175%      173%        --
```

With the: `perl 5, version 16, subversion 2 (v5.16.2) built for darwin-thread-multi-2level` (default OS X)

```
             Rate matchendz     match  matchend
matchendz 0.405/s        --      -69%      -70%
match      1.29/s      218%        --       -5%
matchend   1.36/s      235%        5%        --
```

The **old** perl is faster. ;)

the OS:

```
Darwin jabko.local 13.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.3.0: Tue Jun  3 21:27:35 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2422.110.17~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

---

The last question

- still not tested the effect of precompiled regexes `qr` - any other idea what can be the fastest filter?

Comment: Your test on `rindex` should be `>= 0`. And it's worth trying `sub { my @xml; for my $x (@list) { push @xml, $x if $x =~ /\.xml/ } }` etc. as well.
`

Comment: thanx, Going to add and will update the question with the results.

Comment: @Borodin yes, the `for` is definitely much faster than the `while`. updated the results.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding last question, try `\z` instead of `$` as `\z` matches end of string while `$` also looks for optional trailing newline ([`perldoc perlre`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions)).

```
use Benchmark qw(:all);
my $str = "a38877283.xml";
cmpthese(10, {
    'match'    => sub { $str =~ /\.xml/  for (1..5_000_000) },
    'matchend' => sub { $str =~ /\.xml$/ for (1..5_000_000) },
    'matchend2' => sub { $str =~ /\.xml\z/ for (1..5_000_000) },
});
```

output

```
             Rate matchend2  matchend     match
matchend2 0.473/s        --      -58%      -59%
matchend   1.14/s      140%        --       -1%
match      1.15/s      143%        1%        --
```

Comment: @jm666 btw, I guess your `while` is slower as it calls `each`.

Comment: OK, probably yes, but why that difference between `while` vs `grep` when doing `regex` vs `substr`? All `while` uses the same (ineffective) `each`.

Comment: @jm666 it was using perl 5.10.1 Hm, using 5.20 on same machine gives `match` significant advantage. :)

Comment: Youre right. Checked & updated. I hope later will come @ikegami too, and will give some deeper findings. ;) :)

Comment: @jm666 so it seems that during time perl did some changes in regex engine.